# Twitter Bootstrap: How can I stop the class .Collapse from causing navbar elements to be invisible in high resolutions?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Even the copy-pasted code from getbootstrap.com is facing the same issue.
Here's my custom code that works perfectly in mobile resolution with the collapsed menu. But when the page is wider than 768px the "< li >'s" are just not showing up. No custom CSS was involved with #navbarCollapse it is simply the selector for for the data-toggle.

```
<header class="row">
        <div class="navbar" id="navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="font-family: 'open sans condensed'; font-size: 30px;">Name</a>
                <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navmenu">
                    <li><a href="/">About</a></li><li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End of Navigation -->
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="banner">
                    <h1 class="bannertext">
                     Content <br> 
                    <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary">GET STARTED</button>
                    </h1>
                </div>
    </header><!-- End of header-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution to this using CSS:

Since the menu collapses under `max-width: 768px`, and `.Collapse` sets `display: none;`
it made sense that selecting `#navbarCollapse` by id would over-ride it outside the collapsed mode. Here's the code if you're curious:

```
/* Non-mobile features */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
#navbarCollapse {
  display: block;
}
}
```

Comment: It was a legit question. That was all the code you needed to see, I mentioned Collapse being Display: none; when inspected.